# Stacked inputs with rows using flexbox

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create stacked inputs using flexbox, with the additional ability to also set rows. Here is the code:

```css
.stacked-inputs,
.stacked-inputs .row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.stacked-inputs .row {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.stacked-inputs > input,
.stacked-inputs .row > input {
    position: relative;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 0%;
    flex: 1 1 0%;
    min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="stacked-inputs">
  <input type="text" placeholder="First name">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Last name">
</div>

<br /><br />

<div class="stacked-inputs">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last name">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Job title">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Year started">
  </div>
</div>
```

When inputs are stacked without using rows, they will all be stacked horizontally. However, if a row is used, then obviously the rows of stacked inputs can be divided up nicely. Would love a review of this code from someone. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is my opinion on how to improve your code.

1. You don't need write `flex-flow: row-wrap` because `flex` by default set row, then you can use another property of css `flex-wrap: wrap`.
2. If you want to use flex in the whole of your code, you can set flex properties for `.row` class.
3. Care about responsiveness, because flex is very good for making your page responsive. Due to this, we use `flex-wrap` and `min-width` to our input.

```
.stacked-inputs,.stacked-inputs .row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}
.stacked-inputs .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.stacked-inputs > input,
.stacked-inputs .row > input {
    -ms-flex: 1 1 0%;
    flex: 1 1 0%;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```